# Can I get a simple bool value from another controller in my HomeController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a check for registration in my RegistrationController:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAmARegistrationRepository _RegistrationRepository;
    public RegistrationController(IAmARegistrationRepository registrationRepository)
    {
        _RegistrationRepository = registrationRepository;
    }
    public  bool IsRegistered(string userName)
    {
        return _RegistrationRepository.IsRegistered(userName);
    }
}
```

How can I check this from my HomeController? Is there a way to access the `ControllerBuilder` to pull in the currently open controller if there is one? or to at least be able to generate one using the customer controller factory I've loaded into the `ControllerBuilder` in my `Global.asax.cs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this.  You already have a method on your repository that you can use.  Why create another controller just to invoke a method that simply defers to the repository method?  Create an instance of the repository in your HomeController and use the `IsRegistered` method on it.

Comment: I was thinking for separation of concerns it would be best for registration methods to live in the registration controller and that the single call to check on registration wasn't a good enough reason to constructor inject the `RegistrationRepository`.  Perhaps the `RegistrationRepository` should be a singleton somewhere.

Comment: I wouldn't go the singleton route.  You obviously have a need for registration data in the HomeController so I would inject it there.  I don't think a repository is a good candidate for a singleton and making it one will make your tests harder.

Comment: Depending on the size of your application, this is a good candidate for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

One solution (of many) would be to implement the common function IsRegistered in a BaseController and have both HomeController and RegistrationControlle Inherit from your BaseController.

Comment: +1 I had't thought of that, but i'm just going to go with tvanfosson's idea.